# Wine dont start file exermwspa.exe for Radio Mobile

Tags: linux, wine

I am starting radiomobile in ubuntu, I had downloaded the necessary files to run radiomobile but when I start the `rmwspa.exe` file I get an error

I haven't found any information about it, but a trying but I don't know what to do.

I run this code in terminal

```
wine rmwspa.exe
```

> `001e:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {cacaf262-9370-4615-a13b-9f5539da4c0a} could be created for context 0x1
>   001e:err:olepicture:OleLoadPictureEx IPersistStream_Load failed`

Comment: I am running a VB application from winehq 5.0/ Ubuntu 18.04. Got same error: err:olepicture:OleLoadPictureEx IPersistStream_Load failed